# How to access files outside the DocumentRoot in a VirtualHost in XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have a Virtual Host configured in Windows 7. The project is located in `C:\project` with the following structure:

```
project
  \cache
  \configs
  \htdocs
    \css
    \images
    \js
    \.htaccess
    \index.php
  \includes
    \setup.php
    \en.php
  \lib
  \templates
  \templates_c
```

In my `httpd-vhosts.conf`, I created a VirtualHost:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/project/htdocs"
    ServerName project.dev

    <Directory "C:/project/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And added `127.0.0.1 project.dev` to the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

The problem is that I want the `htdocs` to be the directory from which `httpd` will serve files but I want to include, with PHP, files, for example, located in the `includes` directory.

How can I solve this problem? I already tried so many solutions from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to Apache Alias and `.htaccess` tweaking but none have worked so far. There must have be some easy solution. Maybe I'm not understanding quite correctly the concept of DocumentRoot. I just want to emulate the typical server folder `public_html/www/htdocs` while keeping important files out of the browser/user scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VHost I took from my `httpd-vhosts.conf`. The only extra configuration I made was to get around the 403 I was hitting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "Markdown.loc"
    ServerAlias "www.Markdown.loc"
    DocumentRoot "C:\INTERNAL\PHP\Markdown"
    <Directory "C:\INTERNAL\PHP\Markdown">
        Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All my other VHosts look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/somesite.loc"
    ServerName somesite.loc
    ServerAlias www.somesite.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

If you're simply looking to include something from a dir on the same level as your htdocs though, `include("../includes/somefile.php")` should work just fine.

If I've got your problem wrong, let me know, and I'll try to help you more.

Comment: If in the Directory group I only use `AllowOverride All` like you, I get an 'Access forbbiden' page.

Comment: And, yes, `include("../includes/somefile.php")` works fine. But because all the examples I saw somewhat used absolute paths, I never thought to use this simple relative path. And my previous configuration had DocumentRoot set to "C:/project" instead of "C:/project/htdocs" which wasn't helping (mod_rewrite was doing the rest of the job).

Comment: @RenatoRodrigues Good to hear you got it working! Sometimes the simplest solutions are the ones easily overlooked.

Comment: That's right! But, err, now a new problem appeared. `include("../includes/setup.php")` works fine for files in the root of `htdocs`. In `project/htdocs/admin/index.php`, I have `include("../../includes/setup.php")` (so it goes back two levels). So far, so good. But then, setup.php can't find a file in the `lib` folder because the relative paths; it fails with `require(../lib/Smarty/Smarty.class.php)`.

Comment: This line did the trick in `setup.php:` `require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/lib/Smarty/Smarty.class.php');` I used `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` instead of simply `require(/lib/Smarty...)`. Just hope that this don't break even if I include `setup.php` in a deeper level of `htdocs`

Answer (score 1):

Set your include path within your virtualhost or .htaccess:

```
php_value include_path ".;c:/project"
```

Comment: Would any of this methods let me to include a file regardless of the level I may be in `htdocs`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to the only method that will work regardless of where the file is located or being accessed from within htdocs.

Comment: Thanks! Is this a frequent practice? Or should it be avoided?

Comment: A while back I read some pros/cons about include_path and decided to not use it.  I keep my applications includes/requires consistent to one directory level above the project location (eg. htdocs).  Therefore, unless the file is in the same directory, I'm including '../lib/myClass.php' throughout the project.  I use one directory above the project root since the apps are usually executed from ./htdocs, ./bin, or ./app.