# Making a file not accessible for direct download in PHP/Apache

Tags: php, apache, file, file-io

I want to create a simple app using PHP for uploading videos. But, I want to make sure it is not accessible for download but can be embedded in my app so I can play it. How can I do this?

It was inspired with this question [php restrict access to files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645196/php-restrict-access-to-files-in-directory) but I really don't get how it works.

Comment: This [answer in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645606/1450077) you liked to explains it quite well. Basically, enable PHP to access them via a user permission, but place the files outside your document root - so that users cannot access them via a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it by storing data outside the public DocumentRoot and using PHP to deliver the file.

But i would recommend you to use `.htaccess` file for this purpose.

You can do it with `.htaccess` file like

```
deny from all
```

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess) too.I think this is what you've wanted.

Comment: but, can my app access it for playing purposes of the video?

Comment: btw, how can i directly link to that file if it is outside the document root folder? so i can embed it inside my app

Comment: for tht u would need to do some changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182008/how-to-access-files-outside-the-documentroot-in-a-virtualhost-in-xampp